# I would like to group the rows of this dataset by Index and then sum the rows by common index

Tags: r, dataset, sum, grouping

I would like to group the rows of this dataset by MemberID.

This is a snipet of my dataset "Claims":

```
  MemberID    SopLos    DIH
1     54         0       1
2     55         1       2
3     56         2       3  
4     67         0       5
5     55         1       1
6     54         0       1
7     55         1       2
8     56         2       3  
9     67         0       5
10    55         1       1
```

My desired data frame:

```
  MemberID    SopLos    DIH
1     54         0       1
2     54         0       1
3     55         1       1
4     55         1       2
5     55         1       1
6     55         1       2
7     56         2       3  
8     56         2       3  
9     67         0       5
10    67         0       5
```

Then I would like to sum the rows by common ID's
resulting in the following data frame

```
 MemberID    SopLos    DIH
1     54         0       2
2     55         4       6  
3     56         4       6  
4     67         0       10
```

If you could give me any help I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: As a side note, while cleaning up your formatting, I removed your name because that is "official policy" here; users are discouraged from including "Thanks" or other signatures or taglines. The box in the lower right serves that purpose. It's a minor thing; I generally don't bother unless I'm in there editing other stuff anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data is in a dataframe called `dat`:

```
require(plyr)
ddply(dat,.(MemberID),summarise,SopLos = sum(SopLos),DIH = sum(DIH))
  MemberID SopLos DIH
1       54      0   2
2       55      4   6
3       56      4   6
4       67      0  10
```

Comment: That did the job, Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

Since I only have base functions available at the moment, here's another solution.
Assuming your data is in a dataframe called df:

```
aggregate(df[c("SopLos","DIH")],list(MemberId = df$MemberID),sum)

  MemberId SopLos DIH
1       54      0   2
2       55      4   6
3       56      4   6
4       67      0  10
```

If you have a lot of variables to sum or a dataset that changes frequently and don't you wish to type out all the names, you could also try:

```
aggregate(df[-(grep("^MemberID$",names(df)))],list(MemberId = df$MemberID),sum)
```