# how apply a function across runs

Tags: r, function, plyr, apply

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [R Grouping functions: sapply vs. lapply vs. apply. vs. tapply vs. by vs. aggregate vs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega)

I have a model output file which looks like:

```
run step x
1    1    1
1    2    4
1    3    3
1    1    4 
1    2    5
1    3    6
2    1    5
2    2    4
2    3    7
2    1    3
```

.
.
.
and I need to calculate the mean values for each step according to the run number.How can I do this? Many thanks to anyone, who can help me.
Viola

Comment: I am not familiar with "hey" tag. Who makes "hey" and what is it used for. Is there an open source implementation of "hey"?

Comment: Also dups: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593056/i-would-like-to-group-the-rows-of-this-dataset-by-index-and-then-sum-the-rows-by/9593529

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, this can be done using ddply from the plyr package:

```
require(plyr)
ddply(model_output, .(run, step), summarise, mn = mean(x))
```

Where `model_output` is the model output you read from file.

Comment: Jesus, this is fast! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Or a base R version:

```
aggregate(test["x"],test[c("run","step")],mean)

  run step   x
1   1    1 2.5
2   2    1 4.0
3   1    2 4.5
4   2    2 4.0
5   1    3 4.5
6   2    3 7.0
```